# Does transferring data from iPhone to iPhone using Quick Start keep Screen Time?

Tags: iphone, screen-time

I have a phone that has Screen Time on it, and I some how messed up the reset screen time passcode. I've got a new phone and I want to transfer the data from this phone to the new phone. If I use [Quick Start](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210216) to transfer the data will it keep the Screen Time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Transferring or restoring the phone with a backup will also pass on the Screen Time restrictions.

If you know the password of the the Apple ID used to setup the passcode, you can follow this instructions to reset it:

**On an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch**

> 1. Make sure that your device is updated to iOS 13.4 or iPadOS 13.4 or later.
> 2. Go to Settings > Screen Time.
> 3. Tap Change Screen Time Passcode, then tap Change Screen Time Passcode again.
> 4. Tap Forgot Passcode?
> 5. Enter the Apple ID and password* that you used to set up the Screen Time passcode.
> 6. Enter a new Screen Time passcode, then enter it again to confirm.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211021

Comment: I did that but I think I tapped the button on not entering the apple id which means I can't reset it again. And I forgot the password again. So...

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase or comment on what you really want to achieve. If you want to bypass the Screen Time Passcode without the Apple ID, and keep the phone contents, that is not possible.